# Creating custom layout for DB records

Tags: asp.net

I have a databse table with some columns of data (area inside green), I want to retrieve table data in such layout with paging support, how can I create this layout? (there is no problem for retrieving data from DB) does GridView support such layout?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following article I gues this is exactly what you need: [The asp:ListView control (Part 1 - Building a Product Listing Page with Clean CSS UI)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx)

Comment: The main point of that article is not toprovide step-by-step manual for representing data from database on a page but rather to show features of ListView control. But if you need solution that you can copypast into your project of course this example unsuitable espscially if you don't want to use LINQ.

Comment: Then you may use a Repeater control utilizing the same technique as used in the article I suggested. If it's to complex for you to adopt that article for Repeater I may delete my answer and maybe somebody will provide solution that will be convenient for you.